# Sort images using radio and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Shortly speaking I want to sort Images which already exist depending on their categories using radio buttons - I'm trying do it via adding to special categories images different classes (I don't want to use any additional plugins like sortable etc.). #inside is the radio button id, I have this code:

```
$(function(){
    var allImage = $('img.group1');
    var insideImage = $('img.group1').hasClass('insideThis');
    $('#inside').on('click' , function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(allImage).fadeOut('500');
            $(insideImage).fadeIn('500');
            }
        else {
        }
    });
});
```

and my html looks like below:

```
<ul class="thumbnails image-sort">
          <li class="col-md-2 list-inline">
            <a class="thumbnail" rel="lightbox[group]" href="img/pics/1.jpg"><img class="group1 insideThis" src="images/10.png" title="Image Title" /></a>
          </li> <!--end thumb -->  
          <li class="col-md-2 list-inline">
            <a class="thumbnail" rel="lightbox[group]" href="images/10.jpg"><img class="group1 insideThis" src="images/10.png" title="Image Title" /></a>
          </li> <!--end thumb -->
          <li class="col-md-2 list-inline">
            <a class="thumbnail" rel="lightbox[group]" href="img/pics/1.jpg"><img class="group1" src="images/10.png" title="Image Title" /></a>
          </li> <!--end thumb -->
          <li class="col-md-2 list-inline">
            <a class="thumbnail" rel="lightbox[group]" href="img/pics/1.jpg"><img class="group1" src="images/10.jpg" title="Image Title" /></a>
          </li> <!--end thumb -->   
        </ul><!--end thumbnails -->
```

result is when click radio all of the images fadeOut but this image which has class `insideThis` doesn't want to show. I tried with `addClass` `hidden` and `removeClass` `Hidden` etc. but with no results. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `hasClass()` returns a boolean, not elements, you probably wanted to select the element that has the class

```
var insideImage = $('img.group1.insideThis');
```

or as you already have a collection of the images, you can filter them without doing another DOM lookup

```
var allImage = $('img.group1');
var insideImage = allImage.filter('.insideThis');
```

Comment: Omg right! Just check in console it return true instead of DOM elements , so simple!! Thank You very much, works great!